# how to train voice in Microsoft system.speech?

Tags: speech-to-text, cortana

With a Winforms project in Windows 7, using Microsoft System.Speech v4.0.30319, I was able to create a working project, reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx

I created a custom dictionary, registered event handlers and it runs and works ok. It links in to the default microphone, I added textboxes  and timers on indicators to show events and what it "heard" in my dictionary.  Not perfect but ok;  I added code to process a 'back' command to erase the last thing, or 'clear' to clear out the sentence.  That part works.

But Can something be run to train the voice for each user?  If I apply this program in Windows 8.1 and use Cortana cloud speech, and did training for my voice, will it be applied towards this program?

Or, if in Windows 7, I launch the Speech Recognition and train it, will that become the learned speech that my program uses?